# Flutter order a list based off reference list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listview with some checkboxtilelist in it.  Im trying to maintain the order of the returned selection in the same order as the reference list.  Im generating the checkbox list like this:

```
List<Widget> widgets = [];
for (var o in widget.args.options) {
  widgets.add(
    CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text(o),
      value: widget.args.selections.contains(o),
      onChanged: (v) {
        setState(() {
          v ? selected.add(o) : selected.remove(o);
        });
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

So for example if the list of options is the standard work week of

```
['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun']
```

And they select Wed, then Mon, then Fri it currently returns

```
['Wed','Mon','Fri']
```

But want it to return

```
['Mon','Wed','Fri']
```

Not sure how to go about that, so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you case you cant sort alphabetically becuase you have a specific order, so you can try

```dart
final all = ['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun'];

final selected = ['Wed','Mon','Fri'];

final orderdSelection = all.where((el) => selected.contains(el));

print(orderdSelection ) ///['Mon','Wed','Fri']
```

Comment: Had to tweak it a little bit and copy the list and then use retainWhere for dart as there isnt a where function.  But got me in the right direction and got it working.  Thanks

Comment: @DRing where exists on a list, just FYI https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/where.html

Comment: Huh, it was throwing an error for me...I'll have to look into it then, but got me in the right direction